# Why I keep getting my requests cancelled in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, abortcontroller

I'm doing a gallery, where some items can be loaded as you scroll. I wanted to be able to click on the next page and if currently it was loading more items, it will cancel current request and precede to next page. I'm using `Axios` with `AbortController()`:

Gallery:

```
const controller = useRef<AbortController>(new AbortController());
const loading = useRef(false);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

const search = () => {
  if(loading.current) return;
  dispatch(search(params, controller.current.signal));
}

const cancelSearch = () => {
  if(loading.current){
    controller.current.abort();
    loading.current = false;
  }
}

const pageClick = (selection) => {
  cancelSearch();
  setPage(selection);
  search();
}
```

Actions:

```
const search = (params, signal) => {
  axios.get(`${url}${params}`, {signal: signal})
}
```

After first request is getting successfully cancelled, all my next requests are cancelled as well, even though I'm not calling `cancelSearch()`. I also can't see any new requests in Network tab, as if they are not being done in the first place.

Comment: you abort the controller, but never set it to a new one again, so it remains with the aborted state.  possibly make the controller a state ie, const [controller, setController] ....then do setContrller(new AbortController()) after the current one is aborted

Comment: About `loading.current` I set it in other places as well, so that works fine. Requests always getting cancelled on `Axios` level

Comment: I can see why its cancelled, cause' nothing ever resets that in the code you pasted